# Full Calendar not displaying/loading on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am trying to implement a full calendar on my web page, although when I navigate to the page where it should be, it simply does not display.

Here is my code:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcalendar")

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Forecasts</h2>

<div id='calendar'></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
            weekends: false // will hide Saturdays and Sundays
        })

    });
</script>
```

and here is what is in each of the rendering bundles:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    ~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fullcalendar").Include(
    "~/Scripts/moment.js",
    "~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/fullcalendar.css",
    "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Libary Versions:

```
jquery - 1.11.3
moment - 2.11.2
fullcalendar - 2.4.0
bootstrap - 3.0.0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Added a snippet of the rendered HTML code below. Note: all sensitive information has been replaced with '#'.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index - ###</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="/Resources/logo.png" width="75" height="35" alt="Logo" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">
                    User: ###<br />
                    Date: ###
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">#</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/#/#">#</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/#/#">#</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/#">#</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/#">#</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"></script>

<h2>#</h2>

<div id='calendar'></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
            weekends: false // will hide Saturdays and Sundays
        })

    });
</script>



        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2016 - #.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A. Can you show us the output (html) code but not the server (MCV) code? B. Any errors in the `console`?

Comment: There are no errors in the console and as for the output HTML, do you really need to see this, some of it contains information that I don't want to post here and it shouldn't make any difference as it outputs as expected - is there something I can show you specifically?

Comment: I don't need to see your data (of course) I just need to try to debug it (of course snippet or bin will be better)

Comment: I have added in my output HTML for you and removed any sensitive data, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my own problem, I believe there was some sort of conflict with fullcalendar and bootstrap/respond.js.

In my shared views folder, these scripts were being rendered at the end of the page (which I didn't realise).

I removed these and it worked fine.

Below shows the rendering bundle and below that shows the scripts that are part of that bundle.

```
Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
```